# How to make a more compact ul containing p elements?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to make a more compact , but the compact attribute doesn't work in the structure I am using.
Can someone help me lessen the vertical "margin" of each li?

**Code Snippet**

```html
<main id="main-canvas" style="padding-left: 120px">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="row" style="width:100%">
      <div class="col-9" style="padding-left:0px">
        <div class="row">
          <ul style="padding-left:25px" compact>
            <li><b class="content">123: </b>
              <p class="secondary-content">Lorem</p>
            </li>
            <li><b class="content">456</b>
              <p class="secondary-content"> ipsum dolor sit</p>
            </li>
            <li><b class="content">789</b>
              <p class="secondary-content">amet consecituir or something like that I don't know I don't care</p>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <h3>Some stuff</h3>
        </div>
        <p class="secondary-content">Some secondary content</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-3">
        <div class="row">
          <h3 id="sidemenu-h">sidemenu</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Comment: Warning: Do not use this attribute, as it has been deprecated: use CSS instead. To give a similar effect as the compact attribute, the CSS property line-height can be used with a value of 80%. - [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul)

Comment: The <p> tags have a vertical margin.  So add the Bootstrap class "py-0" to each of these or (easier) replace each with a <div> tag.

Comment: `<p>` tags have default margin not padding. :-) Removing it will help.

Comment: Thanks @Yogi
py-0 didn't work unfortunatelly, but setting margin-bottom on each p as 0px did.

Comment: Thanks @jme11 - you gave the correct answer more simply, so the one to write is as an answer will get the upvote (either you or Yogi)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All right, no one wants to answer so I will do it.
Both @Yogi and @jme11 were right - removing the margin on `<p>` tag coupled with setting the line-height on the ul while removing the compact attribute did the trick.
The final html:

```
<ul style="padding-left:25px; line-height:18px">
    <li><b class="content">123: </b>
        <p class="secondary-content" style="margin-bottom:0px">Lorem</p>
    </li>
    <li><b class="content">456</b>
        <p class="secondary-content" style="margin-bottom:0px"> ipsum dolor sit</p>
    </li>
    <li><b class="content">789</b>
        <p class="secondary-content" style="margin-bottom:0px">amet consecituir or something like that I don't know I don't care</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```